# Merge sort with OpenMP

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp, mergesort

So I am making a program that sorts an aryay with 100.000.000 intengers using the  merge sort algorithm. At the end ,the program prints how much time it took to sort the array and to find its greatest element with 1,2,3 and 4 threads. The "merge time" seems to be right ,with the one thread being the slowest and the four threads being the fastest as expected(t1>t2>t3>t4),but that relation doesn's apply for the "find max" time ... Any ideas why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAX 100000000
#define MAX_THREAD 4

typedef struct thr {
    int thr_low;
    int thr_high;
}thr_t;

void merge(int low, int mid, int high);
void merge_sort(int low, int high);
void multi_merge_sort(int low,int high);
void copyArray(int *A,int begin,int end,int *B);

int *A,*B,found,greatest,num=1,dummy;
double mergetime[4],findmax[4],start_time,maxtime;


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

  A= malloc(sizeof(int) * MAX);
  B= malloc(sizeof(int) * MAX);


  for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    B[i] = rand() ;
    if(B[i]>greatest)
    greatest=B[i];
  }
  do{
    copyArray(A,0,MAX,B);

    thr_t *thr;
    thr_t thrlist[num];
    int len = MAX / num;

    int low = 0;
    found = greatest = dummy = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++, low += len) {
        thr = &thrlist[i];

        thr->thr_low = low;
        thr->thr_high = low + len - 1;
        if (i == (num - 1))
          thr->thr_high = MAX - 1;
     }

    start_time=omp_get_wtime();

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(num)
    {
      int ID = omp_get_thread_num();
      thr_t *thr = &thrlist[ID];
      int low = thr->thr_low ;
      int high = thr->thr_high;
      multi_merge_sort(low,high);
    }

    thr_t *thrm = &thrlist[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        thr_t *thr = &thrlist[i];
        merge(thrm->thr_low, thr->thr_low - 1, thr->thr_high);
    }

    mergetime[(num-1)]=omp_get_wtime()-start_time;
    num++;
  }while(num<=MAX_THREAD);





printf("Merge time:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("%d --> %lf sec\n",(i+1),mergetime[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  printf("Found greatest num in:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("%d --> %lf sec\n",(i+1),findmax[i]);

  free(A);
  free(B);
  return 0;
}



void merge(int low, int mid, int high){

  int p1 = mid - low + 1;
  int p2 = high - mid;

  int *left = malloc(p1 * sizeof(int));
  int *right = malloc(p2 * sizeof(int));

  int i,j,k=low;

  for (i = 0; i < p1; i++){
    left[i] = A[i + low];

    if(greatest==left[i] && found==0){
      found =1;
      findmax[(num-1)]=omp_get_wtime()-start_time;
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < p2; i++){
      right[i] = A[i + mid + 1];
      if(greatest==right[i] && found==0){
        found =1;
        findmax[(num-1)]=omp_get_wtime()-start_time;
      }
    }

  i = j = 0;

  while (i < p1 && j < p2) {
    if (left[i] <= right[j])
      A[k++] = left[i++];
    else
      A[k++] = right[j++];
  }

  while (i < p1)
    A[k++] = left[i++];

  while (j < p2)
    A[k++] = right[j++];

  free(left);
  free(right);
}

void merge_sort(int low, int high){

  int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;

  if (low < high) {
    merge_sort(low, mid);

    merge_sort(mid + 1, high);

    merge(low, mid, high);
  }
}

void multi_merge_sort(int low,int high){

  int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;

  if (low < high) {
    merge_sort(low, mid);
    merge_sort(mid + 1, high);
    merge(low, mid, high);
  }
}

void copyArray(int *A,int begin,int end,int *B){
  int k=0;
  for(int i = begin; i < end; i++){
     A[i] = B[i];
  } 
}
```

Comment: So what times did you measure for finding the maximum ?  On 1 ... 4 threads ?

Comment: 1 --> 0.015000 sec ,
2 --> 0.025000 sec ,
3 --> 0.131000 sec ,
4 --> 0.005000 sec

Comment: First, a possibly unrelated question, but what is the point of that `do` loop? Secondly, I think you might have a race condition when looking for the greatest element, not to mention the time it takes to find it is random anyway. Finally, also a little unrelated, you're sorting a rather large array and every iteration of `merge` creates some temporary arrays, consider making these in advance, two for each thread as the allocation of large arrays takes some time and can hinder the performance of your sorting algorithm.

Comment: @Qubit the do loop runs 4 times .Thats because i want to measure the merging time with 1,2,3 and 4 threads and i do that in every loop. 
The time is not random as there is a start time ,which is measured right before the thread creation, and once he program finds the greatest num of the array it runs the "findmax[(num-1)]=omp_get_wtime()-start_time;" command .
As far the temporary arrays:they are needed because as you can see the merge function calls itself ,as a result it creates more than two arrays.So,it is impossible to make so many arrays in advance .

Comment: @ripmsn First: I see. Second: The position of the largest value is random, it might be the first element in which case you're going to find it very quickly. The concern about a race condition remains. Third: I don't see the merge function calling itself, merge_sort calls merge, sure, but merge does not call itself.

Comment: @Qubit sorry i misread...yeah merge doesnt call itself.however ,with every thread the array is splitted into different sizes ,so i dont know if two static arrays would be a good solution

Comment: @ripmsn Not 2, but 2 for each thread. Still, try running the program some 10000 times and give us the average time it takes it to find the value. Make sure to generate a new random array to be sorted every time.